# The right way to use postgresql with concurrent processes

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I am accessing a postgresql table from Python with psycopg2.  I am doing this from several processes.  I've been using serialization transaction isolation to maintain the integrity of the data.  I do this by checking if there is a TransactionRollback exception while updating / inserting, I try again until the process gets through.  I am experiencing many errors while doing this (in the form of `current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block`.  More than half the data is successfully written to the database, the rest fails due to the above error (which occurs in all of the processes attempting to write.)

Am I approaching postgresql concurrency / transaction isolation with Python and psycopg2 the correct way?  Phrasing another way: is it acceptable to use postgresql serialization transaction isolation, accessing the table from multiple separate processes concurrently?

Comment: Since you haven't shown any code, it's really rather hard to say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At a guess, you are trapping a connection exception but not then issuing a `ROLLBACK` or `conn.rollback()` on the underlying PostgreSQL connection. So the connection still has an open aborted transaction.

The key thing to understand is that catching a psycopg2 exception does *not* issue a rollback on the underlying connection. It's marked aborted by PostgreSQL, and can't process new work until you [issue a `ROLLBACK` on the connection](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/connection.html#connection.rollback).